JSCH-SSH2 verbose debugging
I am trying to enable DEBUG level for Jsch SFTP. Using the latest version i.e.,0.2.18. Implemented a logger required by Jsch to enable logging. I am setting the logger (Log4j instance) just before Jsch object instantiation.
class JSCHLogger implements com.jcraft.jsch.Logger   {
        private Logger jschLogger = Logger.getLogger(SimpleTest.class);
        
        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int arg0) {
            if(arg0 == DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("its in DEBUG mode!!!");
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void log(int level, String message) {
            switch (level) {
            case DEBUG:
                jschLogger.debug(message);
                break;
            case INFO:
                jschLogger.info(message);
                break;
            case WARN:
                jschLogger.warn(message);
                break;
            case ERROR:
                jschLogger.error(message);
                break;
            case FATAL:
                jschLogger.fatal(message);
                break;
            }
        }
    }


JSch.setLogger(new JSCHLogger());
        
JSch jsch = new JSch();

Log4j-config
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, STDOUT
log4j.logger.com.jcraft=DEBUG

I only see INFO level logs. Any suggestions?
